# columns that start with underscore handling

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have code, that is exporting data from selected table, column, and value and creating a CSV file for each combination using spark.sql(). Code is working fine when the column selected is not starting with underscore. Is there a way, how to handle these columns?

Example table: system_mapping

| _column | column |
| --- | --- |
| A | town |
| B | village |

my code:

```
dbutils.widgets.dropdown("column_selection", column_names[0], column_names)
column = dbutils.widgets.get("column_selection")

spark.sql(f"""select * from {database}.{table}
              where {column} = {value})
```

It works when I chose the "column", however not with "_column"

I've also tried to create function like

```
column_enh = f"`{column}`"
```

However, it still hasn't worked. Any ideas?

P.S. can't change the column names

Comment: not able to recreate the scenario.. can you add sample data and Spark version?

Comment: did `spark.sql('select * from db.tbl where \`_column\`="val"')` not work?